# check if element of list exist between two values of another list in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if an element from list exist between two elements for another  list
For example I have list of ages and the other list is agesPeriod

```
agesPeriod : [
{
    min : 10,
    Max : 20
},
{
    min : 30,
    Max : 90
},
],
ages : [10,20,40]
```

Comment: Loop over the `ages` array and then for each value, loop over the `agesPeriod` array and check if `val >= min` and `val <= max`.

Comment: thank you for your  answer ,but is there an another method more optimized using JavaScript functions?

Comment: You could create your own function like what they did [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-if-two-arrays-contain-any-common-item-in-javascript/)

Comment: Can you provide an attempt of your own, as well as showing us what the expected result is? As it stands (and as long as I'm understanding correctly), no age would fall between the bounds of both of those periods, as there is no overlap.

Comment: Optimal solutions to search problems generally involve indexes. If you need help implementing an index in JavaScript, you are in the right place. If you don't know what an index is or which one to use, ask https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you all for your answer yeah it works for me know i will edit the post to add the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
  let result = []  
    agesPeriod.forEach(range => {
      ages.forEach(el => {
          if (el >= range.min && el <= range.max) {
            result.push(range);
          }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one use `array.forEach` and `array.filter`?

```js
let agesPeriod = [
{
    min : 10,
    Max : 20,
},
{
    min : 30,
    Max : 90,
}
]
let ages = [10,20,40]

agesPeriod.forEach(arr =>{
console.log(ages.filter(i=>arr.min <= i && i<=arr.Max ))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const doesItExist = (list1, list2) => {
  let result = false;
  list1.forEach(el => {
    list2.forEach(range => {
        if (el >= range.min && el <= range.Max) {
        result = true;
      }
    });
  });
  return result;
};

console.log(doesItExist(ages, agesPeriod));
```